# Claims on Server and on Client do not match

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4, asp.net-core-3.1, asp.net-core-identity, oidc-client-js

With IdentityServer 4 v4.0 and Asp.Net Core Identity 3.1 I get the claims after login:

```
sub: 1
http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role: Admin
preferred_username: john@domain.com
name: john@domain.com
email: john@domain.com
email_verified: true
amr: pwd
idp: local
auth_time: 1592937212
```

But in [OIDC Client JS](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js/) which I used to login I get:

```
sub: "1"
preferred_username: "john@domain.com"
name: "john@domain.com"
email: "john@domain.com"
email_verified: true
amr: ["pwd"] (1)
idp: "local"
auth_time: 1592937212
```

**Questions**

1. Why am I missing the Role "Admin" on OIDC Client?
2. Why `name` claim is the email and not the user name?

On the OIDC Client the settings are:

```
const settings : UserManagerSettings = {
  automaticSilentRenew: true,
  authority: this.environment.authAuthorityUrl,
  client_id: 'spa',
  filterProtocolClaims: true,
  loadUserInfo: true,
  post_logout_redirect_uri: this.environment.authPostLogoutRedirectUrl,
  redirect_uri: this.environment.authRedirectUrl,
  response_mode: 'query',
  response_type: 'code',
  scope: 'openid profile email offline_access api',
  silent_redirect_uri: this.environment.authSilentRedirectUrl
};
```

On the ASP.NET Core 3.1 Startup I have:

```
  services
    .AddIdentityServer()
    .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
    .AddInMemoryPersistedGrants()
    .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(IdentityConfiguration.GetIdentityResources())
    .AddInMemoryApiResources(IdentityConfiguration.GetApiResources())
    .AddInMemoryApiScopes(IdentityConfiguration.GetApiScopes())
    .AddInMemoryClients(IdentityConfiguration.GetClients())
    .AddAspNetIdentity<User>();
```

And the IdentityConfiguration class is:

```
public class IdentityConfiguration {

  public static List<ApiResource> GetApiResources() {

    return new List<ApiResource> { 
      new ApiResource("api", "API Resource")
    };

  } 

  public static List<ApiScope> GetApiScopes() {

    return new List<ApiScope> { 
      new ApiScope("api", "api")
    };

  } 

  public static List<IdentityResource> GetIdentityResources() {
    return new List<IdentityResource> { 
      new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
      new IdentityResources.Profile(),
      new IdentityResources.Email()  
   };
  }   

  public static List<Client> GetClients(IConfiguration configuration) {

    Settings settings = configuration.Get<Settings>();

    return new List<Client> { 

      new Client {

        ClientId = "spa",
        ClientName = "SPA Client",

        AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
        AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,
        AllowOfflineAccess = true,
        RequireClientSecret = false,
        RequireConsent = false,
        RequirePkce = true,

        AccessTokenType = AccessTokenType.Jwt,
        AccessTokenLifetime = 3600,
        IdentityTokenLifetime = 360,
        RefreshTokenUsage = TokenUsage.ReUse,

        AlwaysSendClientClaims = true,
        UpdateAccessTokenClaimsOnRefresh = true,
        AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken = true,

        AllowedScopes = { 
          IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
          IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile, 
          IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email, 
          IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OfflineAccess,
          "api"
        },  

        AllowedCorsOrigins = settings.Path.AllowedCorsOrigins,
        PostLogoutRedirectUris = settings.Path.PostLogoutRedirectUris,
        RedirectUris = settings.Path.RedirectUris

      }

    };

  }

}
```

**Update 1**

I created the user using UserManager as follows:

```
var user = new User {
  // User properties
}

var claims = new List<Claim> { 
   new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin")
}

await userManager.CreateAsync(user, password);

foreach (var claim in claims) 
  await userManager.AddClaimAsync(user, claim);
```

I checked the database and the User is created and the Claim saved in UserClaims table.

**Update 2**

To include User's FullName I implemented IdentityService's IProfileService:

```
public class ProfileService : IProfileService {

  protected UserManager<User> _userManager;

  public ProfileService(UserManager<User> userManager) {
    _userManager = userManager;       
  } 

  public async Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context) {
  
    User user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(context.Subject);

    List<Claim> claims = new List<Claim> {
      new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Name, user.Name),
    };

    context.IssuedClaims.AddRange(claims);

  } 

  public async Task IsActiveAsync(IsActiveContext context) {

    User user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(context.Subject);

    context.IsActive = (user != null) && user.IsActive;

  }

}
```

This also does something strange. The server Claims are the same:

```
sub: 1
http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role: Admin
preferred_username: john@domain.com
name: john@domain.com
email: john@domain.com
email_verified: true
amr: pwd
idp: local
auth_time: 1592937212
```

And the Client claims become:

```
sub: 1
name: John Smith
amr: pwd
idp: local
auth_time: 1592937212
```

So the Server Claims don't get the Name changed and the Client Claims loose all the emails and preferred_username but get the correct Name.

The Role keeps showing on Server but not on Client.

Comment: How are you adding the "Role" Claim in .Net Core?

Comment: @charbel I am using `.AddAspNetIdentity<User>();`in Startup class. Is this what you mean? I just added my entire configuration to my question. Does it help?

Comment: I mean when you are adding a new user how are you assigning him the role of admin ? can you show us this part of your code please.

Comment: Just added an update to my question. Is this what you meant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- For the first Question try replacing `ClaimTypes.Role` by `JwtClaimTypes.Role`.
- Regarding the second question isn't your username the same as your Email?

**Edit:**

In your `ProfileService` constructor inject `IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory` and apply the following changes to your `GetProfileDataAsync()` function:

```
private readonly IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<User> _claimsFactory;
private readonly UserManager<User> _userManager;

public ProfileService(UserManager<User> userManager, IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<IdentityUser> claimsFactory)
{
       _userManager = userManager;
       _claimsFactory = claimsFactory;
}

public async Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
{
       var sub = context.Subject.GetSubjectId();
       var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(sub);
       var principal = await _claimsFactory.CreateAsync(user);

       var claims = principal.Claims.ToList();
       context.IssuedClaims = claims;
}
```

Comment: But JwtClaimTypes.Name should not be the User's FullName instead of UserName? The OpenId Spec says about Name: End-User's full name in displayable form including all name parts, possibly including titles and suffixes, ordered according to the End-User's locale and preferences. (https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#StandardClaims)

Comment: And the Preferred_UserName would be the Username

Comment: Can you add your `RegistrationModel` to the question please?

Comment: You mean the UserModel? Not sure what you mean.

Comment: I replaced ClaimTypes.Role by JwtClaimTypes.Role and didn't solve it either

Comment: I also implemented IProfileService to try to solve this but makes for bad than good :-(